# I want to query a table in azure data explorer and generate multiple series

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql

So there is a table with the following structure and data.

```
|Code | TimeStamp | Value|
|1 | datetimevalue-1 | 0|
|1 | datetimevalue-2 | 1|
|1 | datetimevalue-3 | 1|
|2 | datetimevalue-1 | 0|
|2 | datetimevalue-2 | 1|
|2 | datetimevalue-3 | 1|
```

I want to plot multiple series for Value and Timestamp grouped by the code. However, there is no need for the aggregate function.

I tried to use make-series but again the need for aggregate function prevents me from doing the same.
I am also open to user-defined functions as long as they are able to get multiple plots for code values.

Also the no of plots, (no of codes to be used for query) are dynamic

Comment: can you show us what's the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

Your data set looks already "aggregated" - perhaps - you just need to 'render' it? For example, 'render timechart':

```
datatable(Code:string, TimeStamp:datetime, Value:long)
[
1,datetime(2019-09-12 19:25),0,
1,datetime(2019-09-12 19:26),1,
1,datetime(2019-09-12 19:27),1,
2,datetime(2019-09-12 19:25),0,
2,datetime(2019-09-12 19:26),1,
2,datetime(2019-09-12 19:27),1,
]
| render timechart
```